# setTimeOut() is not working with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, heartbeat

In my application i want to send something to the server after some time.
I have implemented it using AJAX. But it works for the first time but not doing it recursively. I have used setTimeOut() for doing that.

```
    var xmlHttp;
    var requestURL = 'http://localhost:1092/ClassicAJAXDemo/UpdateHeartbeat.aspx?name=';

    function show_data(strName)
    {
        if (strName.length > 0)
        {
            var url = requestURL + strName;
            xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject(stateChangeHandler);
            xmlHttp_Get(xmlHttp, url);
        }
    }
    function stateChangeHandler()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
            var str = xmlHttp.responseText;
            setTimeOut(show_data('Dev'), 10000); // It is not waiting for 10 seconds.
        }
    }

    function xmlHttp_Get(xmlhttp, url)
    {
        xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }

    function GetXmlHttpObject(handler)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    window.onload = show_data('Dev');
```

Comment: Please show what code you have.

Comment: Use setInterval instead of setTimeout. Edited my code

Comment: Remove the clearInterval method and observe the result.

Comment: Can you inspect using firebug to check for errors?

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of issues in this code segment that are creating your bugs:

### `window.onload = show_data('Dev');`

A bit of explanation about why `window.onload = show_data('Dev');` doesn't work is probably in order:  `window.onload` needs to be a function.  As your code executes, it is evaluating `show_data('Dev')` (which doen't return a value, but does start an XMLHTTPRequest, so it appears to work) and executing `window.onload = undefined;`.

`window.onload=show_data;` would work - but then you don't get your parameter passed.

Luckily JavaScript allows you to create anonymous functions - leading to:

```
window.onload = function() { show_data('Dev'); };
```

### `setTimeOut(show_data('Dev'), 10000);`

First of all, JavaScript is a case sensitive language.  `setTimeOut !== setTimeout`.  Also the first parameter to setTimeout/setInterval is expected to be a function, which suffers from the same problem here as your `window.onload` did, it calls `setTimeout(undefined, 10000);`, but executes the request immediately.  I also think you mean to call it with the same `strName` as it was called with.

Your timeout set should say:

```
setTimeout(function() {show_data(strName);}, 10000);
```

A side note - `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` both allow passing strings that get `eval()`ed at runtime, but I would suggest against using that method which looks like this:

```
// please dont use me
setTimeout("show_data(strname)", 10000);
```

At this point your code should work when edited with those two lines.  The rest of this stuff is just other optimizations

### `setTimeout()` vs. `setInterval()`

This seems like it is going to keep checking every 10000ms, unless the ajax request fails, then it will stop.  I imagine you just wanted to poll forever.  `setInterval()` allows you to setup a "repeating" timer.

Remove your `setTimeout` line and replace `window.onload` with:

```
var updateInterval;
window.onload = function(){ 
  updateInterval = setInterval(function(){ show_data('Dev'); }, 10000);
};

// an example - lets stop polling 35 seconds from now
setTimeout(function() {
 clearInterval(updateInterval);
}, 35000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
window.onload = show_data('Dev');
```

with

```
window.onload = function() {
   var intervalID = setInterval( function(){ show_data('Dev')}, 10000);
}
```

and remove

```
setTimeOut(show_data('Dev'), 10000);
```

from `stateChangeHandler` function.

and don't forget to clear the interval

using

```
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

The difference between `setInterval` and `setTimeout` is that, `setTimeout()` triggers expression only once, whereas `setInterval()` keeps triggering expression again and again (unless you tell it to stop).

Comment: But it is running for 1 time but i want to run it repeatedly.

Comment: Remove the clearInterval method and observe the result.

Comment: Ya i have removed that and it is running for once.

Comment: Can you inspect using firebug is there is any error?

Comment: I got the bug, the bug is
setTimeOut(show_data('Dev'), 10000); [RIGHT]
setInterval(show_data('Dev'), 10000); [WRONG]
setInterval("show_data('Dev')", 10000); [RIGHT (Use double quotes)]


And Thanks very much Phoenix for the help :)

Comment: Edited the code. Please take a look at that.

Comment: Assign a function inside the setinterval.

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
setTimeOut(show_data('Dev'), 10000);
```

could/have you tried:

```
setTimeOut(function() { show_data('Dev') }, 10000);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Your window.onload method is definitely wrong.  replace that with this:

```
window.onload = function(){var intervalID = setInterval(function(){show_data('Dev')}, 10000);}
```

Other answers here seem to cover the other problems so I won't touch that.  cheers